# Angular: How to know if the form is back in initial state?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a reactive form that has some default values and want to disable the save button until the user has changed something and if the user has changed it back to the initial state.

I can subscribe to `valuechanges`, but I want to know if the form is back to initial state after some changes (the user reverted the changes) and disable the save button.

I can't use `Form.dirty` as it becomes dirty once the user has changed something and not `pristine` again if the user has reverted his changes.

Any other way than `JSON.stringify` compare?

Comment: Well, at least here are other options given: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this and settle on a "hash" solution.
Be warned, I haven't thoroughly checked the impact on the perf.
I used to detect changes on 8 average sub-forms of bigger forms with no lag, but still, be cautious.

Let me explain :

- First, I looked for the fastest, lightest hash method I could find and choosed [murmurhash](http://github.com/garycourt/murmurhash-js) from Gary Court.
- Then, when my data is loaded, I store a hash of my pristine form.
- Next, on each value change event from the form, I hash it and compare the result to the stored pristine hash.
- And voilà !

I hope it helps.